# C# windows form application, closing parent form from child

Tags: c#, forms, parent-child

I know this is going to sound a little confusing but here it goes. So i have this parent form and when I  click a button a new child form shows up(note that my parent form its still open). What i want is when i press a button from my child form i want is a new parent form to show up and to close the parent form that was already opening from the beginning. I hope this doesnt sound confusing. I try playing around with it but nothing seems to work
I have something like this on my parent form

```
Form2 loging = new Form2();    
loging.ShowDialog();
```

on my child form

```
Form1 loging = new Form1();
loging.Close()
loging.ShowDialog();
this.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments to Mitch, it sounds like you need to rebind data on your main form after you close the child form.  This is a much better approach than closing/reopening the main form.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you cannot change a window's parent, and you cannot change whether a window is modal.  Destroy the child, close the parent, open a new parent, show a new child.  Alternatively, if the child window need not be modal, create the child with `Form.Show()` and then do something like the following in the child form:

```
parentForm.Close();
Form newParent = new NewParentForm();
newParent.Show();
this.BringToFront();
```

MFC used to be able to fake being modal, but it did so by using a custom window procedure - not something particularly easy to do in C#.

Comment: I try it and it doesnt work, the thing is that i have a list of customers in the parent form(listbox), and with a button I open a new window(note that i need my parent form to be in the background while the child form is open) which i can add a customers name. Once i submit, I want a list of customers including the one i just added.

Comment: I agree with SonicTheLichen.  There is no need to re-create the form if you are just changing the data displayed.  Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx or just clear the listbox and re-add the items after the call to ShowDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment to Mitch, this what you should do:

1. In your parent form, create a static ListView object which point to you customer list

   ```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
       public static ListView lsvCustomer; 
       public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           // this will allow access from outside the form
           lsvCustomer = this.listView1; 
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          frmInput f = new frmInput();
          f.ShowDialog(this);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Then in your child form, you update the list directly from your child form as below :

   ```
   public partial class frmInput : Form
   {
       public frmInput()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           //update user input to customer list in parent form
           Form1.lsvCustomer.Items.Add(textBox1.Text);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: customers names are in an xml file, i have  function in the parent form that reads the names of the customers.